# Pandas non-consecutive number filter dropping 0 row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter a dataset in Pandas. The number must always increase, although this can be in irregular steps. I have set up a filter to ensure any values that are smaller than their predecessor are removed from the DataFrame. This is a simple example I am working with:

```py
test = {"Test": [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 11, 4, 13]}
df = pd.DataFrame(test)
df = df[df.Test.shift() + 1 < df.Test]
```

This works, with the exception that it is also dropping `0` index. i.e. the output:

```py
    Test
1   3
2   5
3   7
4   9
6   11
8   13
```

is missing row `0  1`

Any ideas how to get this row in as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas-series-fillna) with a value that would make the condition true:

```
df = df[df.Test.shift().fillna(df.Test - 1) < df.Test]
```

`df`:

```
   Test
0     1
1     3
2     5
3     7
4     9
6    11
8    13
```

Sample DataFrame that shows intermediate steps:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'shifted': df.Test.shift(),
    'test': df.Test,
    'condition': df.Test.shift() < df.Test,
    'shifted then filled': df.Test.shift().fillna(df.Test - 1),
    'fixed condition': df.Test.shift().fillna(df.Test - 1) < df.Test
})
```

```
 shifted  test  condition  shifted then filled  fixed condition
     NaN     1      False                  0.0             True
     1.0     3       True                  1.0             True
     3.0     5       True                  3.0             True
     5.0     7       True                  5.0             True
     7.0     9       True                  7.0             True
     9.0     2      False                  9.0            False
     2.0    11       True                  2.0             True
    11.0     4      False                 11.0            False
     4.0    13       True                  4.0             True
```

This issue is that in the first case, `NaN` is not less than 1 (`NaN < 1` => `False`).

Answer (score 1):

So try with

```
df[~(df.Test.diff()<0)]
   Test
0     1
1     3
2     5
3     7
4     9
6    11
8    13
```